# Tactic to Propify a bool expression

Tags: coq, tactic

Let's say I have bool expressions `<bexp>` consisting of `true`, `false`, variables, `eqb` `andb`, `orb` and `negb`. When I see an expression of the form `bexp = true` or `bexp = false`, I want to convert them to prop expressions involving `b = true`, `~ b = true`, `b1 = b2`, `b1 <> b2`, `\/` and `/\`.

I want to do this so that I can use the usual tactic machinery like `destruct`, etc to handle them.

For example, if I have a hypothesis

```ml
H: negb b && b0 || eqb b b0 && lexltb bs1 bs2 = true
```

I want it to become:

```ml
H : (~ b = true /\ b0 = true) \/ (b = b0 /\ lexltb bs1 bs2 = true)
```

I have tried implementing it this way:

```ml
Ltac propify :=
  repeat match goal with
  | [ H : ?b1 || ?b2 = true |- _ ] => apply orb_true_iff in H
  | [ H : ?b1 || ?b2 = false |- _ ] => apply orb_false_iff in H
  | [ H : ?b1 && ?b2 = true |- _ ] => apply andb_true_iff in H
  | [ H : ?b1 && ?b2 = false |- _ ] => apply andb_false_iff in H
  | [ H : negb ?b = true |- _ ] => apply negb_true_iff in H
  | [ H : negb ?b = false |- _ ] => apply negb_false_iff in H
  | [ H : eqb ?b1 ?b2 = true |- _ ] => apply eqb_prop in H
  | [ H : eqb ?b1 ?b2 = false |- _ ] => apply eqb_false_iff in H
  end.
```

However, this does not achieve this effect, since it only works at the hypothesis level, and does not further simplify *parts* of hypotheses.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the generalized `rewrite` tactic (enabled by importing `Setoid`) to apply `iff` lemmas under connectives. Use the `in *` modifier to rewrite both in the goal and in hypotheses.

To keep `negb b = true` when `b` is a variable, you need extra care to not indiscriminately rewrite with `negb_true_iff`. Use the `context C [ M ]` pattern to match `M` anywhere within a term (in the goal or in the hypothesis), and `is_var` to check whether something is a variable.

````
From Coq Require Import Setoid.
From Coq Require Import Bool.

Ltac propify :=
  repeat first [rewrite
    ?orb_true_iff, ?orb_false_iff,
    ?andb_true_iff, ?andb_false_iff,
    ?eqb_true_iff, ?eqb_false_iff,
    ?negb_false_iff
    in * |
    (* special case for negb_true_iff to not rewrite with variables,
       and to normalize b = false to negb b = true *)
    match goal with
    | [ |- context C [ negb ?e = true ] ] =>
        tryif is_var e then fail (* backtrack *) else rewrite (negb_true_iff e)
    | [ H : context C [ negb ?e = true ] |- _ ] =>
        tryif is_var e then fail (* backtrack *) else rewrite (negb_true_iff e) in H
    | [ b : bool |- _ ] => rewrite (iff_sym (negb_true_iff b)) in *
    end ].

Goal forall b b0 z,
negb b && b0 || eqb b b0 && z = true ->
negb b && b0 || eqb b b0 && z = false.
Proof.
  intros.
  propify.
(* Goal:

b, b0, z : bool
H : negb b = true /\ b0 = true \/ b = b0 /\ z = true

========================= (1 / 1)

(b = true \/ negb b0 = true) /\ (b <> b0 \/ negb z = true)
 *)
```
````

Comment: I think we want the ? modifier instead of !

Comment: That's true, fixed.